# Pointer to base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, pointers, multiple-inheritance, base-class

If I have the following classes:

```
class A
{
    ...
}

class B
{
    ...
}

class C : public A, public B
{
    ...
}
```

and somewhere I detect that the pointer of class `B` that I have actually points to a class `C`, but a function requires a pointer to class `A`, what can I do to get that pointer to class `A`?

Comment: Post your code. C is already an A, so it doesn't need to be cast.

Comment: Weird. Could you copy paste real code?

Comment: Sorry guys, I got mixed up, now I posted the real problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know for certain that you have a `B*`  that points to a `C` object, you can use a pair of `static_cast`s:

```
B* bp = new C();
C* cp = static_cast<C*>(bp);
A* ap = static_cast<A*>(cp);
```

The only way to cast across the inheritance hierarchy is to use `dynamic_cast`, which requires that the type is polymorphic (that is, your class must have at least one virtual member function; [since your base class destructors should be `virtual`,](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm) this usually isn't a problem):

```
B* bp = new C();
A* ap = dynamic_cast<A*>(bp);
```

`dynamic_cast` has the added benefit that if it fails (that is, if `bp` doesn't actually point to a `C`), it returns NULL.  It has the disadvantage of a slight performance cost (`static_cast` is effectively free at runtime).

Answer (score 1):

If C inherits from A as you have shown, then a C* pointer should be implicitly convertible to an A* pointer. Is it possible that you haven't included the declaration of class C, so that the compiler isn't aware of this inheritance relationship? Or that there is actually a different inheritance relationship than that given in your question? Some code would be helpful in diagnosing this problem.

**Edit**
Based on the updated version of your question:

```
// Converts b to type A*, but only if it is actually
// of type C; otherwise, returns NULL
A* convertBtoAviaC(B* b) {
   C* c = dynamic_cast<C*>(b);
   return c; // note may be NULL, if b is not a C
}
```

Comment: Oh! I just doubled checked. Yes, there's a different inheritance relationship... I'll update the question

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
class A
{
};
class B
{
};
class C : public A, public B
{
};
int main() {
  C c;
  A *a = &c;
}
```

is valid since C is already an A, so the assignment is valid.